# Android studio interface does not redraw after connecting a device

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Android studio interface does not redraw after I connect an ADB device, and it doesn't matter if it's an AVD or a hardware phone/tablet. After device is connected, Studio window becomes grey, and then some (but not all) areas become apparent if I drag mouse over them (see screenshots below).

Event log shows multiple `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions` with the following stack traces:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 300
        at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl$CachedFontContent.addContent(EditorImpl.java:2973)
        at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl$CachedFontContent.access$5400(EditorImpl.java:2914)
        at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl.drawCharsCached(EditorImpl.java:3413)
        at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl.drawCharsCached(EditorImpl.java:3388)
        at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl.drawTablessString(EditorImpl.java:3322)
        at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl.drawTabbedString(EditorImpl.java:3255)
        at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl.drawString(EditorImpl.java:3206)
        at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl.drawStringWithSoftWraps(EditorImpl.java:3185)
        at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl.paintText(EditorImpl.java:2794)
        at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl.paint(EditorImpl.java:1986)
        at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorComponentImpl.paintComponent(EditorComponentImpl.java:153)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:728)
        at com.intellij.ui.components.JBViewport.paint(JBViewport.java:119)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:586)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at com.intellij.ui.tabs.impl.JBTabsImpl.paintChildren(JBTabsImpl.java:2250)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at com.intellij.ui.tabs.impl.JBTabsImpl.paint(JBTabsImpl.java:2245)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at com.intellij.ui.tabs.impl.JBTabsImpl.paintChildren(JBTabsImpl.java:2250)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at com.intellij.ui.tabs.impl.JBTabsImpl.paint(JBTabsImpl.java:2245)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:586)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:586)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.ToolWindowsPane.paintChildren(ToolWindowsPane.java:185)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:586)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:586)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5229)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1572)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1495)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1265)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1040)
        at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:39)
        at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:79)
        at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:116)
        at java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:1973)
        at java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3901)
        at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFrameImpl.paint(IdeFrameImpl.java:506)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:835)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:807)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:807)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:782)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:731)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1300(RepaintManager.java:64)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1720)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:749)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:719)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:697)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:524)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
[ 305215]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Android Studio 1.0.2  Build #AI-135.1653844 
[ 305215]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 1.8.0_31 
[ 305215]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
[ 305215]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
[ 305215]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Linux 
[ 305215]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Last Action: Run 
[ 306163]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - 300
```

or

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -27786341
    at sun.font.FileFontStrike.getCachedGlyphPtr(FileFontStrike.java:472)
    at sun.font.FileFontStrike.getSlot0GlyphImagePtrs(FileFontStrike.java:438)
    at sun.font.CompositeStrike.getGlyphImagePtrs(CompositeStrike.java:115)
    at sun.font.GlyphList.mapChars(GlyphList.java:272)
    at sun.font.GlyphList.setFromString(GlyphList.java:244)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.GlyphListPipe.drawString(GlyphListPipe.java:71)
    at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.drawString(SunGraphics2D.java:2928)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl.drawChars(EditorImpl.java:3426)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl.access$5000(EditorImpl.java:132)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl$CachedFontContent.flushContent(EditorImpl.java:2948)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl$CachedFontContent.access$5100(EditorImpl.java:2914)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl.flushCachedChars(EditorImpl.java:2989)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl.paintText(EditorImpl.java:2865)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl.paint(EditorImpl.java:1986)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorComponentImpl.paintComponent(EditorComponentImpl.java:153)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:728)
    at com.intellij.ui.components.JBViewport.paint(JBViewport.java:119)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:586)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at com.intellij.ui.tabs.impl.JBTabsImpl.paintChildren(JBTabsImpl.java:2250)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at com.intellij.ui.tabs.impl.JBTabsImpl.paint(JBTabsImpl.java:2245)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at com.intellij.ui.tabs.impl.JBTabsImpl.paintChildren(JBTabsImpl.java:2250)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at com.intellij.ui.tabs.impl.JBTabsImpl.paint(JBTabsImpl.java:2245)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5222)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1572)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1495)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1265)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5170)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4981)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:824)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:807)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:807)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:782)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:731)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1300(RepaintManager.java:64)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1720)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:749)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:719)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:697)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:524)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I use Linux x64 and Oracle java 1.8.0_31.

Interface freeze examples:
[image]

[image]

What is the reason? How can I fix this?

**Upd**

Updated to OpenSUSE 13.2, Oracle Java 1.8.0_40, Android studio 1.1.0. Bug is still here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you haven't already found the answer to this, I just had the same problem and found the answer in this thread:

[Android-Studio is unusable with ArrayOutOfBounds exceptions while USB debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28288585/android-studio-is-unusable-with-arrayoutofbounds-exceptions-while-usb-debugging)

Essentially, `sudo zypper rm texlive-arphic-fonts` did the trick for me.