# ArrayOutOfBoundsException in sun.font.FileFontStrike.getCachedGlyphPtr on OpenSuse

Tags: java, fonts, java-2d

Just hit this exception on OpenSUSE Leap42.2j. Linux 4.4.49-16-default using Java 1.8.0_73 25.73-b02 never seen it before

Looks similar to this bug http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=7183251 but says fixed in back in 2012.

Is the bug fixed ?
Is there a way I can avoid it ?

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -34602892
    at sun.font.FileFontStrike.getCachedGlyphPtr(FileFontStrike.java:472)
    at sun.font.FileFontStrike.getSlot0GlyphImagePtrs(FileFontStrike.java:438)
    at sun.font.CompositeStrike.getGlyphImagePtrs(CompositeStrike.java:115)
    at sun.font.GlyphList.mapChars(GlyphList.java:272)
    at sun.font.GlyphList.setFromChars(GlyphList.java:262)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.GlyphListPipe.drawChars(GlyphListPipe.java:103)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.ValidatePipe.drawChars(ValidatePipe.java:178)
    at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.drawChars(SunGraphics2D.java:3036)
    at sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.drawChars(SwingUtilities2.java:847)
    at javax.swing.text.Utilities.drawTabbedText(Utilities.java:187)
    at javax.swing.text.GlyphPainter1.paint(GlyphPainter1.java:119)
    at javax.swing.text.GlyphView.paintTextUsingColor(GlyphView.java:491)
    at javax.swing.text.GlyphView.paint(GlyphView.java:482)
    at javax.swing.text.BoxView.paintChild(BoxView.java:161)
    at javax.swing.text.BoxView.paint(BoxView.java:433)
    at javax.swing.text.BoxView.paintChild(BoxView.java:161)
    at javax.swing.text.BoxView.paint(BoxView.java:433)
    at javax.swing.text.ParagraphView.paint(ParagraphView.java:580)
    at javax.swing.text.html.ParagraphView.paint(ParagraphView.java:233)
    at javax.swing.text.BoxView.paintChild(BoxView.java:161)
    at javax.swing.text.BoxView.paint(BoxView.java:433)
    at javax.swing.text.html.BlockView.paint(BlockView.java:282)
    at javax.swing.text.BoxView.paintChild(BoxView.java:161)
    at javax.swing.text.BoxView.paint(BoxView.java:433)
    at javax.swing.text.html.BlockView.paint(BlockView.java:282)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicHTML$Renderer.paint(BasicHTML.java:481)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthToolTipUI.paint(SynthToolTipUI.java:187)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthToolTipUI.update(SynthToolTipUI.java:141)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:780)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1056)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:586)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5210)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:290)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1272)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5158)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4969)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:831)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:789)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:738)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(RepaintManager.java:64)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1732)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1673)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1625)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar exception was discussed in a bug report for JOSM: [Ticket #9729](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/ticket/9729).

A very relevant information was provided by the user "[stoecker](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/ticket/9729#comment:31)":

> The crashs happen when `texlive-arphic-fonts` is installed, but not
>   `arphic-gbsn00lp-fonts` or `arphic-bsmi00lp-fonts`. Either one of the
>   normal arphic fonts must be installed or the texlive variant must not
>   be installed.

As a confirmation, these 2 other similar questions were solved by removing the `texlive-arphic-fonts` package:

[Android-Studio is unusable with ArrayOutOfBounds exceptions while USB debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28288585/android-studio-is-unusable-with-arrayoutofbounds-exceptions-while-usb-debugging)

[Android studio interface does not redraw after connecting a device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28562354/android-studio-interface-does-not-redraw-after-connecting-a-device)

There is also an open bug report for openSUSE regarding this issue: [Bug 916052](https://bugzilla.suse.com/show_bug.cgi?id=916052)

Comment: Thanks looks like the error, but wonder why texlive-arphic-fonts was installed I doubt the user actively did it, im not clear how you uninstall texlive-arphic-fonts

Comment: @PaulTaylor in one of the linked question it is mentioned that the error was solved uninstalling the font using the command `sudo zypper rm texlive-arphic-fonts`